# Haskell storing composed ADT with Persistent definitions

Tags: database, haskell, functional-programming, yesod

How could I create **Yesod Persistent** Entities which resembles this `ADTs`:

```
import Data.Ratio

data Work = Work { name :: String
                 , payment :: WorkPayment
                 , duration :: WorkDuration }

data WorkPayment = WorkPaymentUndefined
                 | WorkPaymentEstimated { workPaymentEstimatedUnity :: TemporalUnity
                                        , workPaymentEstimatedValue :: Ratio Int }
                 | WorkPaymentTotal { workPaymentTotalValue :: Ratio Int }

data WorkDuration = WorkDurationUndefined
                  | WorkDurationEstimated { workDurationEstimatedUnity :: TemporalUnity
                                          , workDurationEstimatedQuantity :: Int }
                  | WorkDurationPermanent

data TemporalUnity = Hour | Day | Week | Month
```

The long names could be avoided by using separated modules but I preffered putting them all together for this example.

For easy `Enums` it seems quite straight forward but I cannot figure out how will be the tables in this situation like in a **relational database** like MySQL

Answer (score 2):

To store ADTs with Persistent, you just need to tell Persistent how to serialize/deserialize that value from the database. To do that, make it an instance of `PersistField` (to convert it to and from a basic type like `Text` or `ByteString`) and `PersistFieldSql` (to specify what type of database column to use).

You have several options on (de)serializing the data. I imagine encoding/decoding to binary values would be faster, but I recommend JSON because:

- It's human readable from the database level
- Some databases have built-in support for it
- It's portable
- Support is built into Persistent via `to/fromPersistValueJSON`.

Here's an example of that:

```
-- Add this extension to derive To/FromJSON instances; see Data.Aeson for details
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

module Models.Work where

import Database.Persist.Sql (PersistFieldSql(..))
import ClassyPrelude.Yesod
import Data.Aeson

data TemporalUnity = Hour | Day | Week | Month deriving (Generic)

instance FromJSON TemporalUnity
instance ToJSON TemporalUnity

data WorkDuration = WorkDurationUndefined
                  | WorkDurationEstimated { workDurationEstimatedUnity :: TemporalUnity
                                          , workDurationEstimatedQuantity :: Int }
                  | WorkDurationPermanent deriving (Generic)

instance FromJSON WorkDuration
instance ToJSON WorkDuration

-- Store the values as as SqlString. The actual column type will be dependent on the database backend. SqlString will be something like varchar/text types.
-- You can also use PersistByteString, which might be faster
instance PersistFieldSql WorkDuration where
  sqlType _ = SqlString


instance PersistField WorkDuration where
  toPersistValue = toPersistValueJSON
  fromPersistValue = fromPersistValueJSON
```

Here's what it looks like to select from Postgres:

```
foo=# SELECT * FROM "user";
 id | ident  | password |                                               duration
----+--------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  5 | foo123 |          | {"tag":"WorkDurationPermanent","contents":[]}
  6 | bar456 |          | {"tag":"WorkDurationEstimated","workDurationEstimatedQuantity":1,"workDurationEstimatedUnity":"Hour"}
```

I'm not super familiar with native JSON support in MySQL or Postgres, but you may want to look into that if you want to do queries based on the underlying JSON data.